# Linear classification and overlapping problem reduction

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, image-segmentation, linear-systems

I am study linear classification(Y=aX+b) But it is still weakness that is overlapping problem. Could you suggest to me how to reduce overlapping problem in linear classification or how to find these parameters that helpful for overlapping reduction. In my question, I don't considier SVM method because it is more difficult to implement. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to tell what you're asking exactly, but one thing to keep in mind is that not al data is [linearly separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability). You may have to obtain more features from data or try non-linear separation techniques. SVM is one of them, but since you're not considering it, you can try polynomial separation or logistic classifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggesstion. For overloadding problem, some author added some prior term to control parameters a, b in Y=aX+b. For example, Y=aX+b+lambda1(a-a*)+lambda2(b-b*),where a* and b* is prior term. So do you have other scheme to ignore that term